# Criptografias utilizando pilhas em java

Tags: java, string, stack

Em uma mensagem criptografada utilizando pilha para inverter cada palavra de uma *String* e utilizando o *chatAt(int)* para pegar caracteres específicos da mesma, tive o seguinte problema, quando se coloca um caractere na pilha, não se pode usar tipos primitivos como tipo parametrizado.

Como resolver criando uma pilha do tipo *wrapper Character* em vez de declarar uma Pilha de *char* implementando a criptografia e criptografia de mensagem?

Como exemplo o texto "Uma mensagem confidencial" criptografado deve ficar "amU megasnem laicnedifnoc".

Comment: qual é sua duvida?

Comment: Como eu vou empilhar a string e desempilhar criptografada. @DorivalZanetto

Comment: Editei sua pergunta, caso não tenha ficado conforme sua necessidade desconsidere-a, porém mantenha seu conteúdo organizado de forma que facilite o entendimento e deixe sua pergunta enfatizada de maneira clara, por exemplo, "Como faço para usar a pilha dessa forma?".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se você não precisa necessariamente usar pilhas e usa Java 8, tudo pode ser feito de forma bem direta assim:

```
String texto = "Uma mensagem confidencial";
String reverso = Arrays.stream(texto.split("\\s")) //quebra string por espaços
        .map(s -> new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString()) //inverte cada palavra
        .collect(Collectors.joining(" ")); //junto tudo de novo
```

Se não pode usar Java 8, ainda pode fazer assim:

```
String texto = "Uma mensagem confidencial";
String[] palavras = texto.split("\\s");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String palavra : palavras) {
    sb.append(new StringBuilder(palavra).reverse());
    sb.append(" ");
}
String reverso = sb.toString();
```

Se preferir não usar o método pronto de `StringBuilder`, pode recuperar o vetor de caracteres de cada palavra individualmente:

```
String texto = "Uma mensagem confidencial";
String[] palavras = texto.split("\\s");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String palavra : palavras) {
    char[] letras = palavra.toCharArray();
    for (int i = letras.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        sb.append(letras[i]);
    }
    sb.append(" ");
}
String reverso = sb.toString();
```

Enfim, se ainda preferir usar uma pilha por qualquer motivo que seja, pode fazer assim:

```
String texto = "Uma mensagem confidencial";
char[] letras = texto.toCharArray(); //vetor de caracteres
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(letras.length); //buffer contendo resultado
Deque<Character> pilha = new ArrayDeque<>(letras.length); //pilha
for (char letra : letras) {
    if (Character.isWhitespace(letra)) { //se for espaço
        while (!pilha.isEmpty()) sb.append(pilha.pop()); //esvazia pilha
        pilha.clear(); //limpa pilha
        sb.append(letra); //mantém o espaço
    } else {
        pilha.push(letra);
    }
}
while (!pilha.isEmpty()) sb.append(pilha.pop()); //esvazia resto da pilha
String reverso = sb.toString();
```